# Set new placement in Group Criterion via API

Tags: google-ads-api

How can I add new placement (website, for example `www.example.com`) in AdGroup using AdWords API?

I have found

```
    AdGroupCriterionService->mutate,
```

but I need to know ID of website

```
    $adGroupCriterion->criterion = new Criterion($criterionId);
```

So my question:

How I can found ID for any website or exist another way to add new Placement in AdGroup?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
$adGroupService = $user->GetService('AdGroupCriterionService', 'v201509');

$AdGroupCriterionOperation = new AdGroupCriterionOperation();
$AdGroupCriterionOperation->operator = 'ADD';

$AdGroupCriterion = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion();
$AdGroupCriterion->adGroupId = $adGroupId;
$AdGroupCriterion->criterionUse = 'BIDDABLE';
$AdGroupCriterion->AdGroupCriterionType = 'PLACEMENT';

$Placement = new Placement();
$Placement->id = null;
$Placement->CriterionType = 'PLACEMENT';
$Placement->type = 'PLACEMENT';
$Placement->url = $url;

$AdGroupCriterion->criterion = $Placement;
$AdGroupCriterionOperation->operand = $AdGroupCriterion;

$operations = array($AdGroupCriterionOperation);
// Make the mutate request.
$result = $adGroupService->mutate($operations);
```